# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str - Python ZabbixAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, zabbix, zabbix-api

Trying to remove values from a list like I have done previously however I'm running into the above error when running it.

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import csv
import numpy

url = 'http://XXX/api_jsonrpc.php' 

payload = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "event.get", "params": {"output": "extend", "selectAcknowledges": "extend", "selectTags": "extend", "selectSuppressionData": "extend", "selectHosts": ["hostid", "host", "name"], "recent": "true", "sortorder": "DESC"}, "auth": "XXX", "id": 1 }'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json-rpc'}
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, )
geteventlist = r.json()['result']

print(type(geteventlist))

for i in geteventlist:
    i['host'] = i['hosts']['host']
    i['hostid'] = i['hosts']['hostid']
    i['location'] = i['hosts']['name']
    del i['hosts']

file = open('event.csv', 'w+', newline='', encoding="utf_8")

with file:

    header = ['hosts', 'eventid', 'userid', 'acknowledged', 'opdata', 'object', 'name', 'suppressed', 'c_eventid', 'clock', 'source', 'objectid', 'severity', 'urls', 'r_eventid', 'value', 'ns', 'suppression_data', 'correlationid', 'tags']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames = header)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(geteventlist)
```

This is out putting the following:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

The actual data that should be outputted is the following:

```
[{'hostid': '10519', 'proxy_hostid': '0', 'host': 'XXX', 'status': '0', 'lastaccess': '0', 'ipmi_authtype': '-1', 'ipmi_privilege': '2', 'ipmi_username': '', 'ipmi_password': '', 'maintenanceid': '0', 'maintenance_status': '0', 'maintenance_type': '0', 'maintenance_from': '0', 'name': 'XXX', 'flags': '0', 'templateid': '0', 'description': '', 'tls_connect': '1', 'tls_accept': '1', 'tls_issuer': '', 'tls_subject': '', 'proxy_address': '', 'auto_compress': '1', 'custom_interfaces': '0', 'uuid': '', 'inventory_mode': '1'}]
```

I understand that it is coming from a list, however I previously was able to specify the dict in order to byapss this but now I cant get around this error.

Thanks in advance for the help.

[image: Excel CSV]

---

I have just tried to update this with further reading by using a range(len()) addition like the following:

```
for i in range(len(geteventlist)):
    i['host'] = i['hosts']['host']
    i['hostid'] = i['hosts']['hostid']
    i['location'] = i['hosts']['name']
    del i['hosts']
```

However this also produces an error of - "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable"

and if I were to remove the len() from the range() section:

```
for i in range(geteventlist):
    i['host'] = i['hosts']['host']
    i['hostid'] = i['hosts']['hostid']
    i['location'] = i['hosts']['name']
    del i['hosts']
```

I get error - "TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

Comment: what value does `geteventlist` have?

Comment: for example :
`[{'hostid': '10519', 'proxy_hostid': '0', 'host': 'XXX', 'status': '0', 'lastaccess': '0', 'ipmi_authtype': '-1', 'ipmi_privilege': '2', 'ipmi_username': '', 'ipmi_password': '', 'maintenanceid': '0', 'maintenance_status': '0', 'maintenance_type': '0', 'maintenance_from': '0', 'name': 'XXX', 'flags': '0', 'templateid': '0', 'description': '', 'tls_connect': '1', 'tls_accept': '1', 'tls_issuer': '', 'tls_subject': '', 'proxy_address': '', 'auto_compress': '1', 'custom_interfaces': '0', 'uuid': '', 'inventory_mode': '1'}]`

Comment: That example doesn’t have a hosts key to look up values from

Comment: the overarching inventory key where all of these values sit in is called 'hosts'

Comment: Also updated the main post with further information

Comment: Your list has just one element and that element is a dictionary which is key-value pair. Why not try `my_dict = {}` before the loop and then `my_dict['host'] = i['host']`. You don't need `i[hosts][host]`.

Comment: So that removes the error, but how does that incorporate to the bottom of the script where it needs to read those values and write it to a csv file. At the moment all its doing is when I place the headers of the 3 values of 'host', 'hostid' and 'location' i just have blank columns.

And also the value of mydict is only holding 3 values when there is about 519 rows worth of data it should be storing

Comment: If thats a single `hosts` then you probably need `i['hosts'][0]['host']` or to iterate over them

Comment: `for i in geteventlist:

    i['host'] = i['hosts'][0]['host']
    i['hostid'] = i['hosts'][0]['hostid']
    i['name'] = i['hosts'][0]['name']
    del i['hosts']`

error =  " IndexError: list index out of range "

That is the error i get when I use what you have suggested